# Twitter data topical classification

Tags: twitter, bigdata, rapidminer, training-data

So I have a data set which consists of tweets from various news organizations. I've loaded it into RapidMiner, tokenized it, and produced some n-grams of it. Now I want to be able to have RapidMiner automatically classify my data into various categories based on the topic of the tweets.

I'm pretty sure RapidMiner can do this, but according to the research I've done into it, I need a training data set to be able to show RapidMiner how I want things classified. So I need a training data set, though given the categories I wanted to classify things into, I might have to create my own.

So my questions are these:

1) Is there a training data set for twitter data that focuses more on the topic of the tweet as opposed to a sentiment analysis publicly available?

2) If there isn't one publicly available, how can I create my own? My idea to do it was to go through the tweets themselves and associate the tokens and n-grams with the categories I want. Some concerns I have with that are that I won't be able to manually classify enough tweets to create a training data set comprehensive enough so that I can get a good accuracy rate for the automatic classifier.

3) Any general advice for topical classification of text data would be great. This is the first time that I've done a project like this, and I'm sure there are things I could improve on. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There may be training corpora that work for you, but you need to say what your topic or categories are to identify it. The fact that this is Twitter may be relevant, but the data source is likely to be much less relevant to the classification accuracy you will achieve than the topic is. So if you take the infamous [20 newsgroups](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Twenty+Newsgroups) data set this is likely to work on Twitter as well, but only if the categories you are after are the 20 categories from that data set. If you want to classify cats vs dogs or Android vs iPhone you need to find a data set for that.
2. In most cases you will have to create initial labels manually, which is, as you say, a lot of work. One workaround might be to start with something simpler like a keyword search to create subsets of your tweets for which you know they deal with a particular category. Then you create the model on top of that and hope that it generalizes to identify the same categories even though the original keywords do not occur.

   Alternatively, depending on your application (and if you actually want to build an applicaion), you may as well start with only a small data set and accept that you have poor classification. Then you generate classifications, show them to the users of your apps, and collect some form of explicit or implicit feedback on the classification (e.g. users can flag tweets as incorrectly classified). This way you improve your training corpus and periodically update your model.

   Finally, if you do not know what your topics are and you want RapidMiner to identify the topics, you may want to try clustering as opposed to classification. Just create a few clusters and look at the top words for each cluster. They may well be quite dissimilar and describe what the respective clusters are about.

I believe your third question may be a bit broad for stackoverflow and is probably better answered by a text book.